# Laravel Backpack Polymorphic CRUD field

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm wanting to be able to handle polymorphic relations with Backpack CRUD. I can't find any *good* explanations and I'm struggling to unpick its implementation in their other packages (e.g. PermissionManager). What I'm wanting to do is to be able to change the specialties Users & Clinicians are linked to - similar to how roles & permissions change in the Permission Manager.

I have a polymorphic n-n relationship with Users & Clinicians to Specialties. Each model CRUDTrait.

**Specialty Model**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'model', 'model_has_specialties');
    }

public function clinician()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Clinician::class, 'model', 'model_has_specialties');
    }
```

**User Model**

```
public function specialties()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Specialty::class, 'model', 'model_has_specialties');
}
```

**Clinician Model**

```
public function specialties()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Specialty::class, 'model', 'model_has_specialties');
}
```

The pivot table is 'model_has_specialties' and contains:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->integer('model_id');
$table->string('model_type');
$table->integer('specialty_id');
$table->unique(['model_id', 'model_type', 'specialty_id']);
```

I have tried a number of different addField() configurations however I'm really struggling.

**Example of addField() tried:**

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'label' => 'specialties',
    'type' => 'select',
    'morph' => true,
    'name' => 'model_id',
    'entity' => 'ModelHasSpecialties',
    'attribute' => 'model_id',
    'model' => 'App\Models\Clinician',
    'pivot' => true,
]);
```

** Edit **

Here's the ClinicianCrudController which is the link between the clinician class & bootstrap.

```
class ClinicianCrudController extends CrudController
{
    public function setup()
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CrudPanel Basic Information
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Clinician');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/clinician');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('clinician', 'clinicians');

        $this->crud->setColumns(['surname', 'forename', 'title', 'specialties']);

        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'surname',
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Surname'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'forename',
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Forename'
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'select_from_array',
            'options' => [
                'Dr' => 'Dr',
                'Miss' => 'Miss',
                'Mr' => 'Mr',
                'Mrs' => 'Mrs',
                '0Ms' => 'Ms',
                'Prof' => 'Prof',
            ],
            'label' => 'Title',
            'allows_null' => false,
        ]);
        $this->crud->addField([
            'label' => 'specialties',
            'type' => 'select',
            'morph' => true,
            'name' => 'model_id',
            'entity' => 'ModelHasSpecialties',
            'attribute' => 'model_id',
            'model' => 'App\Models\Clinician',
            'pivot' => true,
        ]);


        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CrudPanel Configuration
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        // TODO: remove setFromDb() and manually define Fields and Columns
        $this->crud->setFromDb();

        // add asterisk for fields that are required in ClinicianRequest
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(StoreRequest::class, 'create');
        $this->crud->setRequiredFields(UpdateRequest::class, 'edit');
    }
```

Comment: Where are you using the `$this->crud->addField` you show, is this in your UserCrudController? Just trying to understand the relationship you're wanting to represent in the crud

Comment: Sorry, that is in the ClinicianCrudController class. I've editted my post for this.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Reviewing now, off hand, can you comment out or remove the call to `$this->crud->setFromDb();`? That call sets the column and fields automatically from the database configuration. Im not sure what the behavior would be when calling it after manually configuring the fields as is happening here but I could see that mucking with things, probably best to remove it while testing this.

Comment: Can you also show your `StoreRequest` and `UpdateRequest`?

Comment: Hey @Benjamest are you have solution for this? please share with me. I also have same problem. Thanks